# Google sheets API v4 permissions

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have a sheet that has been shared with me. It has permissions set so that everyone in our company can read it.

I am trying to use Python to read info from this sheet, but am getting PERMISSION_DENIED. Using the same credentials file I can access any other sheets in my Drive, but not this one I have had shared with me - even if I add it to my drive.

What am I missing here?

The code I am using is from [Google's own quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python) with the ID, range and print lines modified. I do not need to go much further than that.

When I test it with Google's own example it works fine.

Comment: Please add the code you're using and the error response you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a json file as credentials and the json was created as a `Service Account`, open that json and retrieve the `client_email` inside it.
Now make sure that the owner has shared the spreadsheet you are trying to read with that email (usually it ends with `.gserviceaccount.com`)